# Custom TextInputLayout class, extra top margin when used in layout files

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

When creating a custom `TextInputLayout` View class, the layout file for the custom class looks normal, but when used in activity/fragment layout files the view puts in some extra top margin and I don't understand why.

Here is the custom view layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="My Custom TextInputLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

When I check the design preview for this custom layout file, it appears normal, with only the small margin for the floating hint:

[image]

And below is the custom view class (I am using ViewBinding in the class, although I don't think this relates to the problem, it still appears with regular `inflate()`):

```
class CustomTextInputLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): TextInputLayout(context, attrs) {

    val binding: CustomTextInputLayoutBinding = CustomTextInputLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)

}
```

So with this all set up, I am using it in an Activity layout, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.vinnorman.customtextfieldtesting.CustomTextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, when I run the app and when I see it in the activity_main.xml design preview, it is putting in a lot more top margin:

[image]

Any ideas as to why there is this extra top margin, and how to get rid of it?

Comment: This is possibly due to it leaving enough space to show the hint there once you start typing. Afaik, the `TextInputLayout` moves the hint smoothly towards the top of the `EditText`. You can test this by using `hintEnabled=false` and removing the hint

Comment: I'm afraid no this isn't the issue. In the first screenshot, there is the correct amount of space for the hint, in the second it adds a lot more. Disabling the hint removes the tiny margin in the first screenshot, and reduces the extra space slightly in the second, but still there is maybe 12dp or so extra margin, with or without the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your layout in the layout inspector, you will see that you have a *TextInputLayout* embedded in a another *TextInputLayout*. This is because your custom view is, itself, a *TextInputLayout* and you inflate another *TextInputLayout* from your layout into it. You don't see this in the Android Studio designer but only on a device/emulator.

The way around this is to use the `merge` tag. See [Use the <merge> tag](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge) for details.

Comment: Perfect, a misunderstanding on my part of the way to make custom classes. They get inflated "inside" the extended View class. I went really lazy with the fix and just extended a FrameLayout to fix it!